# Iteration on rails hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, iteration

I have hash like this , I get value as `params` in my controller

Parameters:

```
{
"utf8"=>"✓",   
"authenticity_token"=>"WwNhv6pbXMvQWamzcKTm6gixDEUvvbrsZ7OrMR8RSAA=",  
"form_holiday"=>{
  "user_id"=>"3", 
  "1"=>{"year_before"=>"2014", "day_before"=>"22", "year_now"=>"2015", "day_now"=>"20"}, 
  "2"=>{"year_before"=>"", "day_before"=>"", "year_now"=>"", "day_now"=>""}, 
  "3"=>{"year_before"=>"2014", "day_before"=>"10", "year_now"=>"2015", "day_now"=>"30"}}
}
```

How can I iterate on this hash and get the values of "1,2,3" ?

I want to change it so it looks like the following:

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", 
 "authenticity_token"=>"WwNhv6pbXMvQWamzcKTm6gixDEUvvbrsZ7OrMR8RSAA=", 
 "form_holiday"=>{
   "1"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "year_before"=>"2014", "day_before"=>"22", "year_now"=>"2015", "day_now"=>"20"}, 
   "2"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "year_before"=>"", "day_before"=>"", "year_now"=>"", "day_now"=>""}, 
   "3"=>{"user_id"=>"3", "year_before"=>"2014", "day_before"=>"10", "year_now"=>"2015", "day_now"=>"30"}}
}
```

and here is my current code:

```
 year_before = ""
  year_now = ""
  holiday = ""
  @users = User.find(:all)
 if params[:form_holiday]

 hash_params = params[:form_holiday]

 hash_params.each do |key, value|
  if value
    value.each do |key2, value2| 
      if key2 == "user_id"      
        holiday = Holiday.where("user_id = #{value2}") rescue nil
      end
      if key2 == "year_before"
        year_before += "#{value2},"
      end
      if key2 == "day_before"
        year_before += "#{value2}"
      end
      if key2 == "year_now"
        year_now += "#{value2},"
      end
      if key2 == "day_now"
        year_now += "#{value2}"
      end
     end
    holiday.year_before = year_before
    holiday.year_now = year_now
    holiday.save                
   end
  end
 end - it doesnt work :(
```

i solved my problem, this solution is good but when i get holiday i got a set of hash and i using year_before on set of hash, it was stupid mistake and i sorry for that and thanks for help

Comment: Why do your parameters look like this instead of having an array of holidays ? Do you have control of the code for the HTML form ? Do you have just "1,2,3" or can there be more/less ?

Comment: i prepare data like this, i control my form but i don't know how do this another way

Answer (score 0):

To get the values, you may try like this:

```
h = params[:form_holiday]
h.each do |key, value|
  value.values.each do |v|
    puts v # v are the values for 1,2,3 etc
  end
end
```

And if you want to get both key and value, you may do something like this:

```
h = params[:form_holiday]
h.each do |key, value|
  value.each do |k, v|
    puts k # k is the key, which would be 1 or 2 or 3 etc.
    puts v # v are the values for 1 or 2 or 3 etc respectively.
    # any operation you perform on k,v
  end
end
```

Comment: i change passing value like this {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WwNhv6pbXMvQWamzcKTm6gixDEUvvbrsZ7OrMR8RSAA=", "form_holiday"=>{"1"=>{"user_id"=>"1", "year_before"=>"2014", "day_before"=>"22", "year_now"=>"2015", "day_now"=>"20"}, "2"=>{"user_id"=>"2", "year_before"=>"", "day_before"=>"", "year_now"=>"", "day_now"=>""}, "3"=>{"user_id"=>"3", "year_before"=>"2014", "day_before"=>"10", "year_now"=>"2015", "day_now"=>"30"}}}
and i

Comment: @PiotroSan Then you don't need to put any condition. I have updated my solution. Please check.

Comment: i edit my post on the top, please help, i don't know what i doing wrong